# Pass Value of Text Area Ajax PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm sure this is simple, but new to AJAX so could do with a pointer. I see others have had this issue but can't find a clear answer.

I have a form with a text area

```
    <form name='comment_form' method="post">
     <textarea  name='comment' id="comment" value="" cols="100" rows="3"/></textarea>
     <input type="button" value="Send" onClick="process_comment();">
    </form>
```

I've stripped this down a lot because there is quite a lot in the form.

So in the Function I set the variable:

```
    var comment=document.getElementById("comment").value
```

And then pass it with ajaxrequest.send like:

```
    comment="+encodeURIComponent(comment)
```

As part of the string, this works fine for text box's on the form, but the text area gives me a value of:

```
   [object HTMLTextAreaElement]
```

I'm sure this contains the value of the Text Area, but I can't find out how to display it. I am using PHP:

```
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
```

Any pointers would be great.

### Thanks.

OK it all works with text box's and I use the same method to set the values for example:

```
    var comment=document.getElementById("comment").value
```

The ajax send is:

```
      ajaxRequest.send("first_name="+encodeURIComponent(first_name)+"&last_name="+encodeURIComponent(last_name)+"&shipping_company="+encodeURIComponent(shipping_company)+"&shipping_address_1="+encodeURIComponent(shipping_address_1)+"&shipping_address_2="+encodeURIComponent(shipping_address_2)+"&shipping_city="+encodeURIComponent(shipping_city)+"&shipping_postcode="+encodeURIComponent(shipping_postcode)+"&shipping_zone="+encodeURIComponent(shipping_zone)+"&shipping_country="+encodeURIComponent(shipping_country)+"&email="+encodeURIComponent(email)+"&order_id="+encodeURIComponent(order_id)+"&order_status_id="+encodeURIComponent(order_status_id)+"&notify="+encodeURIComponent(notify)+"&comment="+encodeURIComponent(comment)+"&date_added="+encodeURIComponent(date_added));
```

All the other values pass through the post variables fine, but the Text Area just comes up with:

```
    [object HTMLTextAreaElement]
```

Comment: Can you post javascript code ?

Comment: Your encapsulation is wrong here `comment="+encodeURIComponent(comment)` - I wouldn't think that would cause the error you're experiencing but that should be `comment=encodeURIComponent(comment);`

Comment: <textarea  name="comment" id="comment" cols="100" rows="3"></textarea> change this

Comment: try `var comment=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("comment").value);` and then pass 'comment=comment' in your ajax

Comment: I [can't reproduce your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/jdJfq/), it likely stems from some error that doesn't appear in the code you've provided in the question.

Comment: @Outlooker tried this but same results. Thanks anyway...

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh Same result. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -2):

You can user jQuery's ajax method.

```
$.ajax({
                         type: 'POST',//GET
                         url: "abc.do",
                         data : {"comments":$("#comments").val(),
                         dataType: 'json',
                         cache: true,
                         context:this.id,
                         success: function(data){},
                        error: function() {},
                        beforeSend: function() {},
                        complete: function() {
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: It's not an answer to his question. Also - if you were to use this, you would need to get the value of `#comments` not just pass over the object or you would have the same error in question.

Comment: Again though, it's not a solution to OP's issue - it's an alternative. Try and fix the actual issue.